# stuck at clickAndWait in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

A recorded test script includes a google search.

After clicking on "Google Search", the next action was to click on a link in the test results, however during playback this happens before the browser has loaded the results,
it stop after search value

here is the code

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>citibank india</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Citibank India: Bank Accounts, Credit Cards, Home / Personal Loans ...</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

if any can advise thanks

Comment: A possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703458/click-clickandwait-not-working?rq=1 This is a markup not a code, your question is not constructive to get any support from the community. please post the recorded script inorder to get a help. Of course, you need to wait for your results to come up. Ideally, a explicit wait. Then find whatever the web element you need. You can easily do clickandwait in Selenium IDE

Comment: Does it stop executing? Did the command fail?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it's better to use a click, and then have a waitForElementPresent for the next command to make sure the next page is loaded.

Klendathu